# Ant Classloader task and java 13

Tags: java, ant, ecj, java-13

I'm upgrading our app from Java 8 to Java 13.   We use Eclipse ECJ in our build process.
To make it work, our ant script has:

```
    <taskdef resource="net/jtools/classloadertask/antlib.xml" classpath="${build-helpers-lib.dir}/ant-classloadertask.jar" />
    <classloader loader="project" classpath="${build-helpers-lib.dir}/ecj-4.13.jar" />
```

This fails when Ant is running under Java 13 with this error:

```
15:50:06  classloader: started Tue Dec 10 15:50:06 PST 2019
15:50:06  WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
15:50:06  WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.classloader.adapter.URLClassLoaderAdapter (file:/home/jenkins/jenkins/workspace/Metrix_2020_1/Metrix-AutomatedBuild/lib/ant-classloadertask.jar) to method java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL)
15:50:06  WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.classloader.adapter.URLClassLoaderAdapter
15:50:06  WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
15:50:06  WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
15:50:06  
15:50:06  classloader: finished Tue Dec 10 15:50:06 PST 2019 (57)
15:50:06  
15:50:06  BUILD FAILED
```

Any suggestions for a workaround?

Comment: I see a start and finish time log entry and a warning. Except for the last line, there is no error. It’s not clear why the build failed.

Comment: Admittedly, I'm assuming that the classloader doing illegal reflection is what is causing it to fail.
The same lines work if run on Java 8.

Comment: The warning says that this kind of hack will stop working in the future, but currently, it still works, but prints this warning. But well, this warning is printed when `setAccessible(true)` is called on the corresponding `Method` object, it doesn’t say anything about an actual invocation attempt. If the `URLClassLoaderAdapter` tries to invoke it on the system class loader, it will fail, as it is not a subclass of `URLClassLoader` anymore. But it would a bad behavior, not to report this failure, i.e. a `ClassCastException` or `IllegalArgumentException`…

Comment: Well, SOMETHING in the call to classloader is failing the ant script.
I can comment out that line and the script works until the next line, which fails with a different error.

Comment: It would be a good move, if the ant extension reported failures correctly. But anyway, in case ant’s class loader is the system class loader, there is no cure, as patching additional URLs into the class path is not supported anymore (it never was, officially). So there’s no way around specifying `ecj-4.13.jar` in ant’s launch class path then…